# Check value in text view

Tags: android, textview

I have a if condition for check value in textview but it still happen only else condition

what I did wrong, why it doesn't have if condition even if I have set lang=space

```
private void setLangTitle() {
    lang.setText(" ");
    db.open();
    Cursor cc = db.getLangAct();
    cc.moveToFirst();
    int index = cc.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_LANG);
    while (cc.isAfterLast() == false) {

        if(lang.equals(" ")){
            lang.append("p"+cc.getString(index));
            cc.moveToNext();
        }
        else {
            lang.append("/" + cc.getString(index));
            cc.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    db.close();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're currently checking if `lang` is equal to a space character. If `lang` is a TextView, than it will not be equal to the space character because it is a TextView object, not a string. You probably want to test if the text being *displayed* on `lang` is equal to the space character, which would be something along the lines of:

```
if (lang.getText().toString().equals(" ")) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that lang is your TextView object? Then you should use `lang.getText().toString()`

Answer (score 1):

you should use

```
if(lang.getText()equals(" ")){
    ...
}
```

You were not comparing texts, you were comparing objects. And, of course, a TextView doesn't (shouldn't) compare equal to a String.